# Evento addEventListener no detecta seteo de Value en Select con formulario dinámico

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, html-select

Tengo un formulario generado dinámicamente con dos elementos select-padre y select-hijo el objetivo es escuchar al select-padre para cambiar los valores del select-hijo, para detectar un cambio en el select-padre utilizo `addEventListener` con el evento 'change' y detecta cambios manuales correctamente. El problema radica cuando seteo el `value` del select-padre y no detecta el cambio realizado.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    document.getElementById('contenido').addEventListener('change', event => {
        if (event.target.id == 'select_padre') { 
          //Se detecto el cambio del select-padre 
        }
    });
});
```

Al setear el elemento select-padre no detecta el evento

```
document.querySelector('#select_padre').value = 1;
```

El código html

```
<select id="select_padre">
   <option value="1">...</option>
   <option value="2">...</option>
   <option value="3">...</option>
   <option value="4">...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi respuesta es apoyada por la respuesta aceptada en la siguiente pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually

Hay un par de formas de hacer esto. Si el `onchange` oyente es una función establecida a través de la `element.onchange` propiedad y no le preocupa el objeto de evento o el burbujeo/propagación, el método más fácil es simplemente llamar a esa función:

```
element.onchange();
```

Si lo necesita para simular el evento real en su totalidad, o si configura el evento a través del atributo `html o addEventListener/attachEvent`, necesita hacer un poco de detección de características para disparar correctamente el evento:

Posterior al seteo que realizas desde el Javascript agregale la siguiente linea:

```
if ("createEvent" in document) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    document.getElementById('select_padre').dispatchEvent(evt);
} else {
    document.getElementById('select_padre').fireEvent("onchange");
}
```

Comparto un ejemplo funcional, basado en el código que suministras, con algunos cambios necesarios:

```js
/**
 * En ves de usar el addEventListener en windows, para agregar el evento onload, llamamos directamente el evento onload.
 */
window.onload = (() => {
  /**
   * En ves de agregarle el evento al elemento con id contenedor, se lo damos directamente al select_padre
   */
  document.getElementById('select_padre').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    console.log('Se detecto el cambio del select-padre ', e.target.value);
  });

  // Dejamos tal cual el seteo que realizas
  document.querySelector('#select_padre').value = 1;

  /**
   * Agregamos el siguiente condicional posterior al seteo,
   * teniendo en cuenta los diversos navegadores, entraría por el if o el else
   */
  if ("createEvent" in document) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    document.getElementById('select_padre').dispatchEvent(evt);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('select_padre').fireEvent("onchange");
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="select_padre">
  <option value="1">Uno</option>
  <option value="2">Dos</option>
  <option value="3">Tres</option>
  <option value="4">Cuatro</option>
</select>
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos

Comment: Buenísimo, gracias por la ayuda, pondré a prueba el código :)

Comment: Revisando el código no veo la forma de implementarlo porque manejo elementos dinámicos, por lo cual el único método que aprendí para capturar el evento es:
```
document.getElementById('contenido').addEventListener('change', event => {
        if (event.target.id == 'select_padre') { 
          //Se detecto el cambio del select-padre 
        }
    });
```

Comment: de igual manera, lo que te puse sirve como lo necesitas, solo vuelves a darle el evento al contenedor como lo tenías y cuando hagas al final el change se lo haces de nuevo al contenedor. También donde creas de manera dinamica el select, puedes allí mismo hacer el addEventListener que te sugerí

Comment: @AntraxSec lo que no logro comprender, es lo que dices sobre elementos dinámicos. Ya que tienes los id, Podrías explicar un poco ese tema a ver como se te puede ayudar mejor.

Comment: No puedo utilizar directamente window.onload porque al cargar el DOM mi formulario aún no existe y eso me difuculta. Por el momento utilizo el método descrito en la pregunta principal if (event.target.id == 'select_padre'). En ese aspecto no logro implementar tu ayuda.

Comment: Lo logre gracias a ti...

Comment: me alegro haber sido de ayuda. Espero tu aprobación en la respuesta. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se hace un cambio programáticamente en un input o un select, el evento "change" no ocurre, tienes que lanzarlo *manualmente*:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('select_padre');

select.addEventListener('change', event => {
  console.log('Valor cambiado a',select.value);
});

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', event => {
  select.value = 3;
  select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});

document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', event => {
  select.value = 4;
});
```

```html
<select id="select_padre">
   <option value="1">Uno</option>
   <option value="2">Dos</option>
   <option value="3">Tres</option>
   <option value="4">Cuatro</option>
</select>

<button id='btn'>Cambia el valor a 3</button>
<button id='btn2'>Cambia el valor a 4 sin lanzar evento</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias enseguida hago prueba.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mantener la funcionalidad actual, solo necesitas crear una función aparte para ejecutar cuando haya cambios en los selects por acción del usuario (eventos) y que tengas la posibilidad de recibir como parámetro el evento o uno de los select.

Siempre que hagas cambios de valor por programación (sin acción del usuario) vas a necesitar ejecutar esa función.

```js
// Crear función que se pueda ejecutar por evento o llamar de forma independiente
function changed(event) {
    let item;
    if(event instanceof HTMLElement) {
        // El parámetro es un elemento
        item = event;
    } else {
        // El parámetro es un evento, tomar de ahí el elemento
        item = event.target;
    }
    // Analizar ID
    if (item.id == 'select_padre') { 
        console.log('Valor del padre: ', item.value);
    } else if (item.id == 'select_hijo') { 
        console.log('Valor del hijo: ', item.value);
    }

}
// Ejecutar cuando se haya cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    // Asignar función por nombre, el evento será enviado como parámetro
    document.getElementById('contenido').addEventListener('change', changed);
});

// Crear variable para facilitar el manejo
let selectPadre = document.querySelector('#select_padre');
// Aplicar el cambio
selectPadre.value = 1;
// Ejecutar función enviando el select como parámetro
changed(selectPadre);
```

```html
<div id="contenido">
    <select id="select_padre">
        <option value="1">...</option>
        <option value="2">...</option>
        <option value="3">...</option>
        <option value="4">...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select_hijo">
        <option value="1">...</option>
        <option value="2">...</option>
        <option value="3">...</option>
        <option value="4">...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

También podría ser un poco más simple, con función anónima y enviando directamente el elemento que disparó el evento:

```js
// Recibir el select por parámetro
function changed(item) {
    // Analizar ID
    if (item.id == 'select_padre') { 
        console.log('Valor del padre: ', item.value);
    } else if (item.id == 'select_hijo') { 
        console.log('Valor del hijo: ', item.value);
    }

}
// Ejecutar cuando se haya cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    // Función anónima, llamando a changed con el elemento que disparó el evento
    document.getElementById('contenido').addEventListener('change', e => changed(e.target));
});

// Crear variable para facilitar el manejo
let selectPadre = document.querySelector('#select_padre');
// Aplicar el cambio
selectPadre.value = 1;
// Ejecutar función enviando el select como parámetro
changed(selectPadre);
```

```html
<div id="contenido">
    <select id="select_padre">
        <option value="1">...</option>
        <option value="2">...</option>
        <option value="3">...</option>
        <option value="4">...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select_hijo">
        <option value="1">...</option>
        <option value="2">...</option>
        <option value="3">...</option>
        <option value="4">...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy intentando implementar el código.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos, aunque aún sigo sin entender por completo el código empleado pude implementarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
document.querySelector('#select_padre').value = 1;

if ("createEvent" in document) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
   evt.initEvent("change", 'consulta_select_hijo', true);
   document.getElementById('select_padre').dispatchEvent(evt);
}
else {
   document.getElementById('select_padre').fireEvent("onchange");
}
```

PD: si alguien puede indicar como enviar parámetros en consulta_select_hijo estaría infinitamente agradecido.